# swift 3.1 reading CSV or PLIST file from web

Tags: ios, csv, core-data, swift3, plist

I'd like to use readStringFromURL method to obtain a file from a plist and then use it on insertDataInArrayFromPlist in order to display it or put it on CoreData, substituting    `let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: plistFileName, ofType: plistFileExtension)`.

the ISSUE  the try statement gives me this ERROR

```
Argument labels '(contentsOfURL:, usedEncoding:)' do not match any available overloads
```

in my viewDidLoad:

```
let obtainedfile = readStringFromURL(stringURL: kremoteSamplePlist)
print(obtainedfile ?? "nothing to print")
```

I retrive the file from web

```
   func readStringFromURL(stringURL:String)-> String!{
        if let url = NSURL(string: stringURL) {
            do {
                return try String(contentsOfURL: url, usedEncoding: nil)
            } catch {
                print("Cannot load contents")
                return nil
            }
        } else {
            print("String was not a URL")
            return nil
        }
    }
```

then I put the data in a struct

```
func insertDataInArrayFromPlist(arrayOfEntities: inout [product]) {

    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: plistFileName, ofType: plistFileExtension)
    let localArray = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path!)!
    for dict in localArray {
        var futureEntity = product()
        let bdict = dict as! [String: AnyObject]
        futureEntity.name = bdict["Name"] as? String
        futureEntity.ProductId = bdict["Product Id"] as? String
        arrayOfEntities.append(futureEntity)
    }

    for element in arrayOfEntities {
        print("name is \(element.name!), the id is \(element.ProductId!)")
    }

}
```

Comment: `return try String(contentsOf: url, usedEncoding:nil)` ?

Comment: tried, but I need to modify in                 return try String(contentsOf: url as URL, usedEncoding: nil)
and got this error : Cannot pass immutable value of type '_' as inout argument

Answer (score 0):

Theres a library available via Cocoapods, CSV.swift by Yaslab.  Allows you to import a csv directly in Swift code and convert to a data type of your own.  Does the job for me.

https://github.com/yaslab/CSV.swift